# Is there a way to have an initial delay for a Spring JMS Listener when connecting to an Active MQ Queue?

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a Spring JMS application that connects to an Active MQ broker when it starts up. What I would like to know is if there is a way to set an initial delay for when the JMS application will start consuming from the queue when initialized.

We are using Spring 4.1.2.RELEASE, and we are using Active MQ 5.8

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `autoStartup` to false on the listener container and call `start()` whenever you want to start receiving messages.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! I used a quartz scheduler to call start() at a specific time.